# JQ Selectable Cancel Selected in Selecting Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using [jQuery Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) and would like to know whether is it possible to prevent Selected event to be triggered from Selecting event?

Actually, I want to show some popup/confirmation in Selecting event, and if user confirms that then I would like the Selected event to be triggered.

Any solution or workaround(or alternative) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean doing something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8VJ/)?

Comment: Actually, I want to show some popup/confirmation in Selecting event, and if user confirms that then I would like the Selected event to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="selectable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="get selected items" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
  selected: function(e, ui) {

    if (confirm('Are you sure to select ' + $(ui.selected).html() + '?')) {
      $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    } else {
      $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
  }

});

$('#btnGet').click(function() {
  var selectedItems = [];
  $('.ui-state-highlight').each(function() {
    selectedItems.push($(this).html());
  });
  alert(selectedItems.join(','));
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/zjexmgfz/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Ali for a quick workaround but I think it won't work in my case. As we know when selected event is fired 'ui-selected' class is automatically applied on selected item(s). That is what the widget is  doing automatically for us so that we don't have to maintain selected/unselected items state ourself.  If we could prevent selected event from firing we don't even have to main another ui-state e.g. ui-state-highlight. And we can count on ui-selected class to get all selected items. With your proposed solution we cannot rely on ui-selected anymore, since it's already applied.

Comment: @AzazulHaq I got it. I updated my code and my demo to do it. Please see it again.

Comment: Thanks for a very quick followup. Again there is a problem with ui-selected state. Lets say, I've selected first two items and then try to select 4th item. 'selected' event is fired and by that time ui-selected is already removed from first two items. Later I press cancel button from the popup, and ends up with 0 ui-selected items.

Comment: @AzazulHaq I got it. In `jQuery selectable` you can select one item by clicking or select multiple item by selecting multiple item with mouse or keyboard. If you select one item or multiple item, finally `ui-selected` is added to the last item. You don't need to this class for selected option, you can get selected items by another class. I updated my answer, please see again.

Comment: Thanks for updating the solution. But with this update, the selectable control doesn't work as the original one(https://jqueryui.com/selectable/). Please observe its behavior. When you select multiple items(by using ctrl button) ui-selected class is applied but as soon as you select single item(without ctrl) all other items are deselected i.e. ui-selected is removed automatically. This is what the widget do so well that it tracks selected/unselected items, and we don't have maintain state our-self. I think if we just can stop propagating selected event from selecting then we are done.